# I need an all IE redirect for website and can't find one that works

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect

I'm currently using

```html
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Though it is not working when testing, i'm running IE v11, is there any reason why this is not working?

Much appreciated and getting a little desperate.

Matt

Comment: Conditional comments stopped working in Internet Explorer 10. Why do you want to redirect all Internet Explorer users?

Comment: It's due to an issue I'm having with a htaccess login form, IE doesn't like it, so whilst i'm getting that sorted, i just want to put something in place so IE users login via index1 as oppose to index nothing major, but just a temp fix.  For IE 10+ then would i drop the IF and just gor for <!-[IE]>  ??

Comment: No form of conditional comments works in IE10+. You should use Stack Overflow to help you fix that form in IE instead of trying to redirect users to another login page. You don't want to maintain two login pages.

Comment: should i start a new question then, as new to stacked overflow

Comment: A new question would be appropriate. I'll watch for it.

Answer (score 0):

The code does look fine. Might be conflicting Javascripts causing the error? Try using the META tag instead :

```
 <!--[if IE]>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.google.com">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Conditional comments do not work in IE10+. Please test your answer first before posting.